# Cutting 2D shapes from 2D shapes and storing the remainder

Tags: php, database, shapes

I have a 10 by 10 sheet of paper. If I remove a 8 by 6, I want to be able to store the remainder as two shapes (that is 2 by 10 and 10 by 4) into a database. Now, if I need to use a 10 by 4, I should be able to cut it from the 10 by 4 but then this should also update the dimensions of the 2 by 10.

[Yellow is the initially removed 8*6, blue and red is the 2*10, green and red is the 4*10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Rqv.png)

I tried storing them separately but I do not know when/how to ascertain when the dimension of the new required piece are now interfering with both the shapes

Comment: I can't go into specifics, but I think you'd need to deal with shapes _and_ coordinates. You removed an 8x6, but it is also important to say _where_ you removed that. Unless you are deleting the 10x10 from the database, performing logic elsewhere, and inserting a 2x10 and a 10x4. However, I think the storage is actually arbitrary, and might be best as just a string (or JSON) unless you actually want to use the database's logic for performing geometric calculations.

Comment: Yes, I will be deleting the 10 X 10 and then storing the 2X10 and the 10X4. However, these cannot technically coexist which is why they have to be adjusted on the next cut

Comment: You either have a collection of dimensions, with the assumption in your business logic that you are dealing with rectangles, or you have a single potentially irregular shape. I think the choice mostly comes down to whether you want to do anything special in the database besides storing things. It really feels like your logic is all in PHP and you are just storing facts, so personally I'd just store them as a string that happens to be JSON (_not_ a JSON database type) or possibly just a delimited list.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, my main worry is making the adjustments so it's more like a logical problem rather than a technical one. I can store them in whatever way, but I still won't be able to process them

Comment: You mean the actual logic for cutting things? How to write that? I'm not clear.

Comment: In this instance $a = 10, $b= 10, $c = 8, $d = 6
Now, I need to store 2, 10, 4, 10 on the database. This part is okay
Now, when I get a 4X10, I want to change the 2X10 so that it becomes a 2X6. My challenge is figuring out when the new cut is interacting with the 4X10 and 2X10 that we would have previously stored

Comment: Is your "cutting" always uniform and in guaranteed locations? For instance, could the 2x10 "cut" happen in the middle leaving you++ with a 3x3 and a backwards "L" shape? How do you know that a 2x10 and 4x10 overlap? And how also do you know that the 2x10 is the vertical one, not the horizontal one? Just "business logic"?

Comment: The cutting is uniform and structured. It's from left to right or top to bottom. In this case, as long as the cut happen from any corner (as is the standard), the 2X4 will remain and so will the 10X4

Comment: In that case, presumably you have a database of paper with IDs. I'd make a column called "sizes" with a string of your possible sizes, such as `10x10` to start with. You get the paper from the database, do PHP logic, and replace that row's sizes with `2x10;4x10`. On the next cut, you grab the entire row, do PHP logic, and replace it with `2x4;2x6;2x8`. Optionally, every time you cut and end up with only rectangles, mark the original as "done" and insert each new rectangle as dedicated rows. By "only rectangles", I don't mean potential rectangles (like the first cut), but actual ones, btw.

Comment: My biggest issue is figuring out where the 2 shapes intersect each other

Comment: I’m trying both to answer as well as to make this question more clear. You are asking both storage and logic question. If we’re talking about intersection, then we can ignore the database for now. My recommendation would be to update the question with this focus. Also include anything that you’ve tried.